# From array attribute to bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, chef-infra

I have two attributes like these:

```
default['cookbook']['array1'] = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
default['cookbook']['array2'] = [ "x", "y", "z", "w" ]
```

I need to pass these attributes as variables to a template like this:

```
template "/tmp/some.sh" do
  source "some.sh.erb"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode "0755"
  variables(
      :bash_array1 => node['cookbook']['array1'],
      :bash_array2 => node['cookbook']['array2']
  )
end
```

In my bash script i need to have two arrays which will have each, the value of the two array above, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
inputs1=( "a" "b" "c" "d" )
inputs2=( "x" "y" "z" "w" )
```

What's the simpliest way to do it?

Thank you,

Gabriel

EDIT:
The sh.erb file with what I've tried until now looks like this:

```
####### the original sh file #########
#inputs1=( "a" "b" "c" "d" ) #this is the original sh file
#inputs2=( ""x" "y" "z" "w" )
####### end of the original sh file #########
```

What I've tried:

```
inputs1=<%= @bash_array1 %>
inputs2=<%= @bash_array2 %>
```

and the result:

```
inputs1=[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ] #which cannot be used
inputs2=[ "x", "y", "z", "w" ] #which cannot be used
```

The end result in my sh should be

```
inputs1=( "a" "b" "c" "d" )
inputs2=( "x" "y" "z" "w" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking beyond just how to use Erb template syntax within a Chef template. Erb has two main directives, `<% %>` for non-printing control code and `<%= %>` for printing expression values to the output. You can access the variables you pass in via `@name` (so for example `@bash_array1`). Write some Ruby code which generates the output you want.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my problem. Indeed, my problem is that I have little to no knowledge about ruby and if I wasn't clear about that, I apologies. What I need is to know how do I get from array attribute to bash array. Thanks again.

Comment: There isn't a specific way you do it, you need to write some code. Use the basic building blocks I mentioned, with that you can write out any format you want.